# Inputting Date without time

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

Using the code below, the google sheet enters the Date in column 6 when a cell in column 1 is edited. It also includes the timestamp.

How can this code be altered so that just the date (day-month-year) is entered? This would allow searches by date on the sheet.

```
  function onEdit(e) {
    var sheetName = 'Cases Allocation'; //name of the sheet the script should work on 
    var colToWatch = 1
    var colToStamp = 6 //timestamp in col A
    if (e.range.columnStart !== 1 || e.source.getActiveSheet()
        .getName() !== sheetName || e.value == '') return;
    var writeVal = e.value !== "" ? new Date(),: '';
    e.source.getActiveSheet()
        .getRange(e.range.rowStart, colToStamp)
        .setValue(writeVal);
}
```

Comment: Set the format.

Comment: [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format) could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`Utilities.formatDate`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format). This method formats date according to specification described in Java SE SimpleDateFormat class. You can visit the date and time patterns [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). An example of usage is:

```
// This formats the date as Greenwich Mean Time in the format
// year-month-dateThour-minute-second.
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
Logger.log(formattedDate);
```

Do take note that using `Utilities.formatDate` has the following effects as noted in this [post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/100644):

> 1. `Utilities.formatDate` does not change the cell format; it converts
>      its content to text. If you are going to use the date value in
>      computations, you don't want it to be converted to text.
> 2. `Utilities.formatDate` requires one to specify a timezone. If you put
>      something like "GMT+1" and your country observes Daylight Saving
>      Time, you can expect hard-to-track bugs to come up a few months
>      later. With setNumberFormat, the date value remains consistent with
>      all other date values in the spreadsheet, governed by its timezone
>      setting.

To avoid these, you can also use [`setNumberFormat(numberFormat)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)) to set the date or number format. The accepted format patterns are described in the [Sheets API documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats). And an example usage is:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
// Always show 3 decimal points
cell.setNumberFormat("0.000");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sheetName = 'Cases Allocation'; //name of the sheet the script should work on 
    var colToWatch = 1
    var colToStamp = 6 //timestamp in col A
    if (e.range.columnStart !== 1 || e.source.getActiveSheet()
        .getName() !== sheetName || e.value == '') return;
    //var writeVal = e.value !== "" ? new Date(),: '';
    e.source.getActiveSheet()
        .getRange(e.range.rowStart, colToStamp)
        .setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
}
```

The below code will save the date without time. You can change the format as required. The field remains a date which can be used as required.

```
setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
```

Comment: This only appears to apply formatting, but doesn't enter a value that is without a time. If I run this code, then look in the value editor of the spreadsheet, I see a time. Compare this to a fresh cell where I manually enter just a date, and don't see any time at all.

This seems to work better, even though it's returning a string and not a date. By the time it's in the cell, it seems to do what I'm looking for: new Date().toDateString()

Comment: When you see a date in a cell (without time), the time is assumed to be 0,0,0,0. When you want to add or substract or do any calculation of a date, you are able to do it only with .getTime() function, which returns the date/time as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all - tried format etc, but then just decided to add a column and split the date and time, with just the date going into a new column.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, Adam. Posting own comments as answers are not permissible and would lead to downvote thus lose of reputation. Please follow the Help Center https://stackoverflow.com/help. I would also advise you to remove this answer. Thank you